# Prevent Multiple Submissions with JQuery Prompt Save Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a save button that triggers a jquery prompt (click the save button, and then I prompt the user: "Are you sure you want to save updates?"  The problem is that a user can click the prompt multiple times, causing the same data to save multiple times.  How can I disable the prompt save button on the first click?

I am using knockout js.  Here is the code in my viewmodel:

```
$.prompt("Are you sure you want to save? You will not be able to change your decision after it's been saved.", {
    title: "Save?",
    buttons: { "Save": true, "Cancel": false },
    submit: function (e, v, m, f) {
        if (v) {
            e.disabled = true;
            response = saveUpdates(LoanDetails);
        }
    }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think there is an extra `closing brace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the button after saving data for the first time. You can use different jquery selector for your button.

```
$('button[type=submit], input[type=submit]').attr('disabled',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try disabling the button itself when you do the save. Then the button
>   wont be clickable and you wont get the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable a button using jQuery, you should have a look at `$('#elem').prop(property,value)`, which will allow you to do something like this...

```
$("input").prop("disabled",true);
```